# Is there a race condition when one thread is constantly querying a variable from memory while another thread updates it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, mutex, race-condition

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>


class A
{
    public:
        A(int n) : num_workers(n) {
            counter_lock = new std::mutex();
            threads = new std::thread[num_workers];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++) {
                threads[i] = std::thread(&A::run, this);
            }
        }

        ~A() {
            delete counter_lock;
        }

        void start() {
            go = true;
            counter = 0;
            total = 1000000;

            while (counter < total) {};

            for (int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++) {
                threads[i].join();
            }
        }

        void run() {
            printf("Spinning\n");
            while(1) {
                if (go) {
                    int i;
                    counter_lock->lock();
                    i = counter++;
                    counter_lock->unlock();
                    if (i >= total) break;
                }
            }
            printf("Done\n");
        }
    private:
        std::mutex* counter_lock;
        std::thread* threads;
        int num_workers;
        int counter;
        int total;
        bool active;
        bool go;
};

int main() {
    A a = A(10);
    a.start();
}
```

In the constructor of `A` I create a thread pool of `num_workers`. They are all executing a function `A::run` which simply waits until it gets a signal to `go` and then starts incrementing the `counter`. The function `start` is meant to be synchronous with whomever called it, so in this case it should be synchronous with `main`. Therefore, it just idles until the `counter` reaches `total` after issuing the signal to `go` to all the worker threads.

The code works as expected. The `counter` ends up at `10000010` which makes sense because each of the `10` threads have incremented the `counter` once before quitting.

Is there a race condition here that I'm not noticing? Is the fact that I'm reading `counter` in the `while(counter < total) {}` loop without a lock causing any problems?

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: I replaced the `while (counter < total) {}` loop with the following, perhaps more thread safe, implementation. But, very rarely, it still ends up looping forever since the value of `counter` hasn't updated.

```
while (1) {
    int c;
    counter_lock->lock();
    c = counter;
    counter_lock->unlock();
    if (c >= total) break;
};
```

Comment: That code looks a bit Java-esque in how most everything is new'd up and never delete'd. Why is the mutex behind a pointer? Why don't you use a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr<[]>`? Also, yes, continually reading the same plain non-volatile variable, without any synchronization, while it gets updated asynchronously, is a race-condition, and will probably be optimized out.

Comment: `bool go;` -- Don't be surprised how things like this will work for multithread programs and synchronization.  It isn't as simple as this, where you can control things using mere `bool` types. 
 That's why there are things such as `std::atomic`.  In addition, that `lock` `unlock` stuff you have going is not recommended, and especially if between the `lock` and `unlock` an exception is thrown.  That's why `std::lock_guard` exists.

Comment: Yes, there is a race condition.   You need to synchronise access to the variable.   For example, using a mutex that both reader and writer threads lock before they access/modify the variable. and each releases it after.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: @Deduplicator why would I want to use a `std::vector`, just curious ?

Comment: For your array of threads I would use a `std::vector`, or at least a `std::unique_ptr<[]>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how do you suggest I replace the `bool go` behavior? I need some way to notify the threads that they can start working.

Comment: @Carpetfizz That is done by using condition variables.  The problem with using `bool` just like that is that a compiler optimizer might take a look at that code, and optimize out what `go` is doing or move things around.  See the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).  Code that looked like yours may have worked some 10 or so years ago, but that is no longer the case due to the aggressive optimization strategies that modern compilers use these days.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the insight! I didn't know that compiler optimizations could actually change the behavior of the program.

Comment: @Peter thanks, I realize that sometimes the `while (counter < total)` loop executes forever because `counter` hasn't been updated. Please see my Edit.

Comment: @Carpetfizz -- For example, the compiler sees you setting `go` to true.  Nothing would stop an optimizer to say *"what difference does it make where `go` is set to `true`, since it wasn't initialized anyway.  Might as well set it to `true` on construction and move it out of start()."*  -- See what I mean?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie understood, thank you!

Comment: @Carpetfizz The optimizer tries to select the most efficient code which conforms to the programs defined behavior. If the defined behavior isn't what we thought, how could it ever know? It will simply relentlessly apply the rules, without trying to second-guess you.